# csv to json conversion error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I use csvtojson convertor to convert in json format.

```
 var csvFileName = path; //path== filepath

 var csvConverter = new Converter();

 csvConverter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {

 console.log('in json object', jsonObj);


   });

 csvConverter.from(csvFileName);
```

csvtojson convertor convert in this format.

```
{ csvRows: 
   [ {  { 'id\tname\talias\tdescription\timages\tprice\tcompare_price\tcollections\tbrand\tquantity\tsku\tbarcode\tcategories\tpublish\tvariants\tstate\tavg_rating\tnum_reviews\tweight\tfree_product\toption_set': '525ba1b3f96404a56a000006\tbraclet12\tbraclet12\tundefined\t\t100\tundefined\tundefined\tundefined\tundefined\tundefined\tundefined\tundefined\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t' }];
```

but I want in this format-

```
{ csvRows: 
   [ { id: '51f21e7c60c058bc54000001',
       name: 'dummy product',
       alias: 'dummy-product1111111111',
       description: 'Lorem Ipsumuuu',
       images: '',
       price: '55',
       compare_price: 'undefined',
       collections: 'undefined',
       brand: 'undefined',
       quantity: 'undefined',
       sku: 'undefined',
       barcode: 'undefined',
       categories: '',
       publish: '1',
       variants: undefined,
       state: undefined,
       avg_rating: undefined,
       num_reviews: undefined,
       weight: undefined,
       free_product: undefined,
       option_set: undefined }]
```

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Your help and ideas are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It returns the string of the JSON object.

You should use `console.log('in json object', JSON.parse(jsonObj));` instead of `console.log('in json object', jsonObj);` to make it in JSON object form.